# Maximum of subGaussians is subGaussians?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

If $X_i, ...., X_d$ are [$b$-subGaussians](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/36788/subgaussians.pdf), for any $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$:

$$
\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq \mathbb{E} e^{t^2 b^2 / 2}
$$

Then for $Z = \max_{i=1}^n X_i$ I think I can write (since it is one of those subGaussian variables):
$$
\mathbb{E}e^{tZ} \leq \mathbb{E} e^{t^2 b^2 / 2}
$$

which proves that it is subGaussian with the same parameter.

Am I correct?

---

Update: Actually now I think I am wrong.

$$
\mathbb{E}e^{t\max_i X_i} = \mathbb{E}\max_i e^{tX_i}  
$$

Now in order continue the argument I need to be able to bring the max outside the expectation. However Jensen's inequality tell me that: 
$$
\max (\mathbb{E}Y) \leq \mathbb{E} \max Y
$$

Which is the reverse of the direction I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true. As your reference states, a necessary condition for $Z$ to be subgaussian is that $\mathbb{E}Z = 0$. However, that is not true in general.

For a simple example that's easy to compute explicitly, let $X_i$ be independent Rademacher distributed. Then $Z=-1$ with probability $2^{-n}$ and $Z=1$ with probability $1-2^{-n}$, so $\mathbb{E}Z = 1-2^{1-n} >0$.

Comment: Any ideas about about $Z - \mathbb{E}Z$? (I think even this is not).

Comment: I would guess so, though not with the same parameter $b$. Not sure how it would scale exactly.

Comment: @p.s. Even though some authors assume that subgaussian are mean $0$ to begin with, that's not universal, and general definiitons do exist, for example see this book: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#, P. 25, proposition 2.5.2 (specially part (iv) where he states an equivalent condition for mean $0$ subgaussians) and the definition 2.5.6 on P. 28. One key relevant point is that in subgaussians we care about tail properties, irrespective of the mean.